# Python C extension for a function that sleeps

Tags: python, c

I'm writing a [Python extension](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) for the functions provided by a GPIO driver. I made progress pretty easily on the simple functions like set_bit() and clear_bit(). But now I need to implement wait_int(), which sleeps until an event is sensed on an input pin and I'm not sure the right way to orchestrate this between c and python. Here's a stripped down example of using the function in c:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;

    //some setup like testing port availability, clearing interrupts, etc
    ...

    while(1)
    {
        printf("**\n");
        c = wait_int(1);//sleeps until an interrupt occurs on chip 1
        if(c > 0) {
            printf("Event sense occured on Chip 1 bit %d\n",c);
            ++event_count;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    printf("Event count = %05d\r",event_count);
    printf("\nExiting Now\n");
}
```

Do I just expose wait_int pretty much directly and then do whatever the python equivalent idiom of the infinite loop is? There's also some debouncing that needs to be done. I've done it in c but maybe it could be moved to the python side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything on the Python side, you can just treat it as a synchronous function.  On the C side, you just block until the event occurs, possibly allowing interrupts.  For example, take a look at the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/73e7bebb3aa4/Modules/timemodule.c#l1518) of the [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep) function:

```
/* LICENSE: http://docs.python.org/license.html */

/* Implement floatsleep() for various platforms.
   When interrupted (or when another error occurs), return -1 and
   set an exception; else return 0. */

static int
floatsleep(double secs)
{
/* XXX Should test for MS_WINDOWS first! */
#if defined(HAVE_SELECT) && !defined(__BEOS__) && !defined(__EMX__)
    struct timeval t;
    double frac;
    frac = fmod(secs, 1.0);
    secs = floor(secs);
    t.tv_sec = (long)secs;
    t.tv_usec = (long)(frac*1000000.0);
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    if (select(0, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &t) != 0) {
#ifdef EINTR
        if (errno != EINTR) {
#else
        if (1) {
#endif
            Py_BLOCK_THREADS
            PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
#elif defined(__WATCOMC__) && !defined(__QNX__)
    ...
```

All it does is use the `select` function to sleep for the given period of time.  `select` is used so that if any signal is received (such as `SIGINT` from hitting Ctrl+C at the terminal), the system call is interrupted and control returns to Python.

Hence. your implementation can just call the C `wait_int` function.  If it supports being interrupted by signals, than great, that will allow the user to interrupt it by hitting Ctrl+C, but make sure to react appropriately such that an exception will be thrown (I'm not certain of how this works, but it looks like returning `NULL` from the top-level function (`time_sleep` in this example) will do the trick).

Likewise, for better multithreaded performance, surround the wait call with a pair of `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS`/`Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros, but this is not required, especially if you're not using multithreading at all.

Comment: that was easy. while True: wait_int()

Comment: If I put this in a python thread, it blocks any other threads until there's an interrupt.

Comment: Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS fixed it.